Common server for multiple vscode instances
I am remaking a vscode extension: Compat IntelliJ File Opener (63342)
This extension open a server on the port 63342 to open links from chrome devtools in vscode, this protocol comes from the IntelliJ Remote API
I've almost reworked everything, my last problem is that as it open a server on a specific port, it can only work on the vscode instance that opened the server.
To make it work with multiple instance, I need the server instance to be able to communicate with other instances or to start a separate server and every instances would communicate with it.
For now the only thing I think would be to use websockets so every instances would connect to the server and the server would forward requests to all of them.
This introduce a lot of problems :

if the server is separate from the extension, then we would need to start it manually or keep it running all day.
if the server is integrated, how to handle when it is closed, would another instance would auto promote as server
if server is started by extension, is it possible to keep the server running in name of another instance.

What would be the best way to keep it simple, cross-platform and efficient.
